# Is UnitTest++ too minimal for practical use

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unittest++

I've been assigned with a task to prepare an evaluation of C++ unit testing frameworks we could use for our next project and I was enchanted by minimalism and simplicity of UnitTest++. However I'm quite concerned whether it's array of tools isn't by any chance too minimal.

For example I can imagine a situation when certain class have a signed int member, that can't be negative, but I can't test it with assert because UnitTest++ have only equality assertion. It wouldn't be so bad if I could use normal CHECK supplied with some custom message, but AFAIK there is no support for custom logging.

I firmly believe the creators of UnitTest++ knew what they were doing, when they decided any assertion other than true, equals or throws is fringe enough to not bother implementing. Nevertheless I'd like to hear from someone using this framework, if you ever ran into any problems due to lack of features available in other frameworks.

Comment: _"I can't test it"_: I'm pretty sure `CHECK_EQUAL (true, x > 0)` is ok.

Comment: Wouldn't that show in the log as "true not equals false" instead of actual value? In this case it would be fine but usualy it's useful for debugging to see how variable differ from expected value.

Comment: No problems here, I'm happy about it (being minimal is part of that happiness). But yeah, I don't see custom logging included. You can add your own probably in few lines.. just overloading check macros maybe? To keep the string somewhere. And run the test runner with custom reporter printing the global string. That example should be `x >= 0` BTW (to test for non-negativeness).  ... BTW... the "string" is TEST NAME ;) That's why it's enough for me.

Comment: @ReverentLapwing You are right - it's pretty limited. I just wanted to mention that it's possible in some way.

Comment: The `CHECK_EQUAL (true, x > 0)` will log something like "expected true, actual false" ... so not good for you. You need meaningful test names (so "fail" is enough info without value shown), or create your own reporter + macros to support it with additional detail message.

Comment: *"but usualy it's useful for debugging to see how variable differ from expected value."* ... a good unit test should be stable. So you don't need this. You simply rerun the failing test with breakpoint to see what happens. To have the value in logs gives you chance to realize what went wrong even without looking at code, but with my common turn-around times (about 0.1s-0.5s to compile new version and under 1s to run all tests) I don't mind breakpointing into test either.